# Создание адаптера для ListView

Tags: android, listview, adapter

Здравствуйте. Зашел в тупик при создании адаптера для `ListView`. Если начинать с начала, то есть `ArrayList`, содержащий список объектов `Week`. Каждый объект `Week`, в свою очередь, содержит список объектов `Day` с 2 полями: `header` и список объектов `Subject`. Ну и каждый `Subject`, соответственно, тоже имеет список полей.
Вывод данных в `ListView` должен быть следующим: идет вывод данных из конкретного объекта `Week` так, что сначала идет header объекта `Day`, а после него - данные из каждого `Subject` этого `Day`. При этом данные из `Subject` и `header` имею разные `Layout`'ы.
Это очень трудно описать, поэтому сделал примитивную зарисовку.

[image: Описание]

Может кто-нибудь подсказать по этому поводу? Заранее благодарю за ответ.

Comment: Посмотрите, например, [сюда](http://stacktips.com/tutorials/android/listview-with-section-header-in-android).

Comment: @post_zeew я видел такое, но проблема в том, что у меня header является обычным String, а Subject - объект с 7 полями. А в данном примере данные однородны.

Comment: Чуть позже добавлю ответ.

Comment: @post_zeew спасибо, буду ждать

Comment: уже дали ответ на вопрос с использованием ListView, похоже, но немного отличается от эскиза. Чтобы получить вид как на эскизе можно воспользоваться CardView и RecyclerView

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Создаем `layout`-файлы:

**activity_main.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**item_header.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#64B5F6">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_header_text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:padding="16dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**item_content.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#E3F2FD">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_content_subject_first_field_text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="4dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_content_subject_second_field_text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="4dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_content_subject_third_field_text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="4dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Создаем классы модели данных:

**Subject**:

```
public class Subject {
    private String mFirstField;
    private String mSecondField;
    private String mThirdField;

    public Subject(String firstField, String secondField, String thirdField) {
        mFirstField = firstField;
        mSecondField = secondField;
        mThirdField = thirdField;
    }

    public String getFirstField() {
        return mFirstField;
    }

    public void setFirstField(String firstField) {
        mFirstField = firstField;
    }

    public String getSecondField() {
        return mSecondField;
    }

    public void setSecondField(String secondField) {
        mSecondField = secondField;
    }

    public String getThirdField() {
        return mThirdField;
    }

    public void setThirdField(String thirdField) {
        mThirdField = thirdField;
    }
}
```

**Day**:

```
public class Day {
    private String mHeader;
    private ArrayList<Subject> mSubjects;

    public Day(String header, ArrayList<Subject> subjects) {
        mHeader = header;
        mSubjects = new ArrayList<>(subjects);
    }

    public String getHeader() {
        return mHeader;
    }

    public void setHeader(String header) {
        mHeader = header;
    }

    public ArrayList<Subject> getSubjects() {
        return mSubjects;
    }

    public void setSubjects(ArrayList<Subject> subjects) {
        mSubjects = new ArrayList<>(subjects);
    }
}
```

**Week**:

```
public class Week {
    private ArrayList<Day> mDays;

    public Week(ArrayList<Day> days) {
        mDays = new ArrayList<>(days);
    }

    public ArrayList<Day> getDays() {
        return mDays;
    }

    public void setDays(ArrayList<Day> days) {
        mDays = new ArrayList<>(days);
    }
}
```

Создаем адаптер для `ListView`:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private static final int TYPE_CONTENT = 0;
    private static final int TYPE_HEADER = 1;

    private ArrayList<Day> mData;

    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Day> data) {
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        mData = new ArrayList<>(data);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return position % 4 == 0 ? TYPE_HEADER : TYPE_CONTENT;
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mData.size()*4;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mData.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        int viewType = getItemViewType(position);
        View v = convertView;

        switch (viewType) {
            case TYPE_CONTENT:
                ContentViewHolder contentViewHolder;
                if (v == null) {
                    v = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_content, null);

                    contentViewHolder = new ContentViewHolder();
                    contentViewHolder.itemContentFirstSubjectTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.item_content_subject_first_field_text_view);
                    contentViewHolder.itemContentSecondSubjectTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.item_content_subject_second_field_text_view);
                    contentViewHolder.itemContentThirdSubjectTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.item_content_subject_third_field_text_view);
                    v.setTag(contentViewHolder);
                } else {
                    contentViewHolder = (ContentViewHolder) v.getTag();
                }
                contentViewHolder.itemContentFirstSubjectTextView.setText(mData.get(position / 4).getSubjects().get(position % 4).getFirstField());
                contentViewHolder.itemContentSecondSubjectTextView.setText(mData.get(position / 4).getSubjects().get(position % 4).getSecondField());
                contentViewHolder.itemContentThirdSubjectTextView.setText(mData.get(position / 4).getSubjects().get(position % 4).getThirdField());

                break;
            case TYPE_HEADER:
                HeaderViewHolder headerViewHolder;
                if (v == null) {
                    v = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_header, null);

                    headerViewHolder = new HeaderViewHolder();
                    headerViewHolder.itemHeaderTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.item_header_text_view);
                    v.setTag(headerViewHolder);
                } else {
                    headerViewHolder = (HeaderViewHolder) v.getTag();
                }

                headerViewHolder.itemHeaderTextView.setText(mData.get(position / 4).getHeader());

                break;
        }
        return v;
    }

    public static class HeaderViewHolder {
        public TextView itemHeaderTextView;
    }

    public static class ContentViewHolder {
        public TextView itemContentFirstSubjectTextView;
        public TextView itemContentSecondSubjectTextView;
        public TextView itemContentThirdSubjectTextView;
    }
}
```

Создаем **MainActivity**:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ArrayList<Week> mWeeks;

    private CustomAdapter mCustomAdapter;
    private ListView mListView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);

        ArrayList<Day> days = new ArrayList<>();

        for(int i=0; i<5; i++) {
            ArrayList<Subject> subjects = new ArrayList<>();
            for(int j=0; j<4; j++) {
                subjects.add(new Subject("Header #" + i + ", subject #" + j + ", field #0", "Header #" + i + ", subject #" + j + ", field #1", "Header #" + i + ", subject #" + j + ", field #2"));
            }
            days.add(new Day("Header #" + i, subjects));
        }

        mWeeks = new ArrayList<>();
        mWeeks.add(new Week(days));

        mCustomAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this, mWeeks.get(0).getDays());

        mListView.setAdapter(mCustomAdapter);
        mCustomAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

В итоге получаем такое:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А если header должен быть не каждые 4 элемента, а в зависимости от длины списка Subject'ов каждого Day? Тогда position / 4 не сработает.

Comment: @ahgpoug, а размер `mSubjects` у всех `Day` одинаков?

Comment: Уже не важно, все сделал. Спасибо за предоставленный ответ.