# Как сделать подобие ScrollView в который напихали LinearLayout?

Tags: android, android-studio, listview, прокрутка, menu

Нужно сделать подобное, но не знаю как. Это какой-то ScrollView в который напихали LinearLayout-ов а в них уже всяких вьюшек? Или это ListView каким-то образом реализованный? 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Знакомьтесь - ListView создаешь xml как надо пишешь адаптер и готово)

Comment: Ок, допустим. Но при использовании ListView необходим кастомный вид вот этих, так называемых, карточек с вьюшками, разделенных divider-ами (Типа шаблон) который потом применяется на них всех. А мне необходимо чтоб эти "карточки" отличались. Конкретно в Этом мое непонимание.

Comment: Ну можно посидеть подумать и с ListViev сделать , а как вариант LinearLayout тоже можно

Comment: Конкретно для настроек есть спец. набор https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html?hl=ru . Если же нужно своё реализовать, то скорее всего список с разными разметками элементов.

Comment: Пример ListView с разными разметками: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/574216/17609

Comment: Но лучше, конечно, на RecyclerView делать: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/522489/17609

Answer (score 3):

Именно то, что на скрине (каждая "карточка" имеет отличную от других разметку и содержимое, большая часть которого статична) из ваших вариантов, проще будет реализовать через несколько `Layout` в `ScrollView`, чем через `ListView` и тем более `RecyclerView` (никакой выгоды от ресайклервью, кроме дополнительного набора кода, в данном случае получить не удастся), которые предназначены для вывода однотипного контента в повторяющиеся элементы.

А вообще такое делают (как правильно указали в комментариях) на основе классов [Preference/PreferenceFragment](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html?hl=ru)

Comment: Pavlofff, ваш ответ - именно то, что я ждал, потому что и сам так думал. Спасибо, что подтвердили мои предположения:)

Answer (score 0):

Читая ответ товарища [pavlofff'a](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/723146/211117) мне почему то хочется сделать замечание по ответу. Здесь как напрашивается recyclerView в который Вы без особого труда сможете разместить Ваши элементы причём двумя способами.

Вы можете сделать 1 ViewHolder в котором добавите несколько параметров такие как например checkBox: Boolean, и там где его надо Вы будете его показывать, там где нет, соответственно не будете)
Или же если такая "карточка" используется ещё где то, то можете отдельно вынести, после чего в самом презентере будете возвращать список item'ов которые Вас интересуют, но этот способ немного сложней будет для Вашего примера.